# Laravel (Eloquent)

Tags: php, database, laravel

I want to know how to make relationship using laravel Model & Eloquent.

I have data structur something like this

**UserTable**

```
username
groups
id
```

**GroupTable**

```
id
name
remark
```

My question is how to display user groups (user can assign to many groups)
and how to count how many users that assigned to each group.

thanks.

**Update**

```
public function store(Request $request){
    $member = new Member();
    $member->username = $request->input('name');
    $member->gender = $request->input('gender');
    $member->joindate = $request->input('joindate');
    $member->remarks = $request->input('remarks');
    if ($request->hasFile('photo')) {
        if ($request->file('photo')->isValid()) {
            $path = $this->upload($request);
        }
    }
    $member->save();

    foreach ($request->only('groups[]') as $key => $group){
        $pivot = new pivot();
        $pivot->user_id = ????? //how to get user id?
    }
}

public function upload(Request $request)
{
    $path = $request->file('photo')->store('profile');
    return $path;
}
```

is that right?
and how to get currently saved **user_id** (it has auto increment column).

Answer (score 0):

You will need to create a pivot table assigning each user to their respective groups.

so basically your tables would be like:

**User Table**

```
id
username
```

**Groups Table**

```
id
name
remark
```

**User -> Group Pivot Table**

```
user_id
group_id
```

Then you can use an Eloquent relationship on your user model to define your relational method like so:

```
class User extends Model {

    public function groups() {

        return $this->belongsToMany(Group::class, 'user_group_pivot_table_name', 'user_id', 'group_id');

    }

}
```

Finally, you can return a collection of all the user’s groups by doing the following:

```
$user->groups();
```

The [Laravel documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many) on the Eloquent ORM is phenomenal too.  Happy hunting.

Comment: public function store(Request $request){
  $member = new Member();
  $member->username = $request->input('name');
  $member->gender = $request->input('gender');
  $member->joindate = $request->input('joindate');
  $member->remarks = $request->input('remarks');
  if ($request->hasFile('photo')) {
   if ($request->file('photo')->isValid()) {
    $path = $this->upload($request);
   }
  }
  $member->save();
  
  foreach ($request->only('groups[]') as $key => $group){
   $pivot = new pivot();
   $pivot->user_id = ????? 
  }
 }

Is that right? and how to get user_id (auto inc)?

Comment: See updated answers! You can then go through the collection with a foreach loop.

Comment: As for your comment, I assume you are trying to store an avatar? If this is the case, make sure that once you've uploaded the file that you also assign in to the user so that you know which image to show on their profile.  The beauty of pivot tables with Laravel is their employment is transparent.  It will seem as though the User model is communicating with the Group model, though of course as we know this isn't exactly the case.  You need only ensure that when a user 'joins' a new group, that you create a new entry in the pivot table showing this.